# Craft 3.1: value of craft/web/Application::getIsLive() must be of type boolean, null returned

Tags: craft3

I tried upgrading a Craft 3.0 installation to 3.1, and got the following error:

> "value of craft/web/Application::getIsLive() must be of type boolean, null returned"

Has anyone else run into this?  Does anyone know a fix?

Comment: hmm, not sure, but. Have you tried surfing to `yoursitename.com/admin/settings/plugins` ? Think you will have to accept some database updates.

Comment: It's erroring out on the admin side of things too.

Comment: I know but you have to allow Craft to make some database changes before 3.1 can work.

Comment: OK, how do I do that when the entire admin panel is also throwing errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved this by adding `'isSystemLive' => true` in general.php

Answer (score 1):

> "value of craft/web/Application::getIsLive() must be of type boolean, null returned"

If you're getting that, then `$this->getProjectConfig()->get('system.live');` (which is what that line is using), is returning something other than `true` or `false`, then some update along with the way in all of your attempts didn't complete correctly.

If you happen to have a 3.0.x database backup from before you started this available, then try restoring from that and attempting the update to 3.1 again noting any errors you might be receiving during the update process first.